# Как очистить содержимое ListView при условии если там накапливается более 500 строк?

Tags: delphi

Как очистить содержимое ListView при условии если там накапливается более 500 строк?

Comment: мб:

           listview.items.clear()  

?

Comment: А как будет выглядеть условие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно так: повесить таймер со срабатывание ивента через каждые 200 милисекунд и в самом ивенте написать: if (ListViewn.Items.Count > 500) then ListViewn.Items.Clear().
Просьба не пинать за написание, т.к. Делфи у меня нет, писал по памяти.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает как надо. Сделал так:
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
if (ListView1.Items.Count > 500) then
begin
ListView1.Items.Clear();
end;
end;

Answer (score 2):

Можно в событие **OnInsert** поставить условие.